# Evitar foco a elemento hijo de div deshabilitado mediante estilos

Tags: angular

Tengo un div el cual deshabilito mediante css, ese div contiene un input el cual a traves del mouse no se puede acceder pero con tab si permite hacer foco en el.
Probé colocando un tabIndex="-1" en el input pero no funciono, sigue permitiendo acceder a el mediante la tecla tab.

Como puedo evitar que se haga foco en el sin tener que hacer un disabled al input?

```html
<div class="d-flex" [ngClass]="{'disabled': isDisabled}">
                        <div class="width-percent-30 label">
                            <label>Número</label>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <input  [inputFormControl]="form.get('number')">
                        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar la propiedad `pointer-events: none` (no recibe eventos de puntero)

```
input {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Y adicionalmente agregar `onfocus="this.blur()"` para quitar el foco apenas lo reciba, debido a uso de tab u otra manera de enfocar.

En el ejemplo se asigna la clase css `.noclick`

```css
.noclick {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="d-flex" [ngClass]="{'disabled': isDisabled}">
                        <div class="width-percent-30 label">
                            <label>Número</label>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <input onfocus="this.blur()" class="noclick" [inputFormControl]="form.get('number')">
                        </div>
</div>
```